# bot returning the wrong number

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I'm Trying to make a tax calculator but it's returning something strange..
Here's the function:

```py
async def tax(args):
  args3 = 5
  protax= round(int(args)*args3/100)
  if protax == 0:
    protax = 1
  return protax
```

here is where I call the function:

```py
    c.execute("SELECT price FROM netflix ")
    netfprice = c.fetchall()
    netprice = netfprice[0][0]
    newnet = netprice*amount
    withtax = await tax(args=newnet)
embed = discord.Embed(
      title="tax system",
      description=f"tax:{netprice + withtax}")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Sidtho Host. | Requested by - {message.author}")
    await message.respond(embed=embed)
```

For this example let's use amount = 2, netprice = 3999.

It returned 4199, but should've returned  7998 + 400, So 8398.

Comment: Did you post all of the relevant code? With your example values, the function should've returned `400`.

Comment: No I didn't wait let me edit the code. Sorry, By the way: I did make it send netprice + withtax

Comment: Since you print `netprice + withtax`, again, it should have printed `4399` (neither `4199`, nor `8398`). Which output do you expect to be 8398? What function returns, or what you have in `description` sting?

Comment: Yeah true it was 4399 Sorry for my mistakes. I expected `description` to return 8398, and the tax func to calculate

Comment: Okay I feel really dumb after seeing my mistake ... I found it

Comment: If you find it was caused by a typo, feel free to close the question :)

Comment: I should've just put a newprice instead Yeah.. I answered it So other's won't have the same mistake as me..

Answer (score 0):

I feel really dumb after seeing my mistake...
my mistake was in the embed description.. Here:`description=f"tax:{netprice + withtax}")`

I should've made it `description=f"tax:{newprice + withtax}")`